# register my app to show in 'complete action using dialog'

Tags: android

I am trying to add my application o the dialog 'complete action using dialog'. This dialog appear when user click on home button.

Here are the dialog:
[image]

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below intent filter  for your Activity

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```